# Delete a value from jsonb array data having no key in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE mine_check.meta
(
  sl_no bigserial NOT NULL,
  tags jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]'::jsonb
);
```

Table looks like

```
    sl.no    tags
    1        [120,450]
    2        [120]
    3        [450,980,120]
    4        [650]
```

I need to delete 120 from the tags column - having no key

I tried reading many places - there they had key to update or delete.

How should I progress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that it has to be done the hard way - unnest the JSONB array, select and filter from it and aggregate back into a JSONB array.

```sql
select sl_no, 
(
  select jsonb_agg(e::integer) 
  from jsonb_array_elements_text(tags) e 
  where e <> 120::text
) tags
from mine_check.meta;
```

Comment: I'm using 9.4 postgress version - jsonb_agg is not supported in that - is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, under PG 9.4 you may replace `jsonb_agg(e::integer)` with `json_agg(e::integer)::jsonb`. TIme to update though.